# How do I filter a jquery form submission through a Button

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am submitting one of my forms in the following way where I needed to do some processing before it get submitted. So I can't use 
`Submit` type button. When I changed it to `Button` type and submitted the form using jQuery.

My form, button set and jQuery looks like:

```
<form id="materialreceiveform"  action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Materialreceive_control/handleForm" method="post">

<td>
    <input id="savebutton" type="button" value="Save" class="btn" name="btnsave" />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn" name="btnupdate" />
</td>
<td><a id="reprint" target="_blank" class="btn" href="">Re-print</a>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="submit" value="Clear All" class="btn" name="btnclear" />
</td>


<script>
    $( "#savebutton" ).click(function() {
        var myDate =  moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        $('[id$=hiddentime]').val(myDate);
        $( "#materialreceiveform" ).submit();
    });
</script>
```

In my PHP controller I caught this submission by using an `isset` before where the button type was in `Submit`. But now after making it `Button` and submitting through jQuery I cant capture the submission by `isset` value as follows.

```
public function handleForm(){

    if(isset($_POST['btnsave'])){

    //code goes here

    }

}
```

Please help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: what do want exactly?

Comment: what is your form action?

Comment: I need to execute the code inside that if condition, when I submit the form

Comment: <form id="materialreceiveform"  action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Materialreceive_control/handleForm" method="post">

Comment: `So I can't use "Submit" Type Button` ... Yes you can. Why not using the 'submit` event, doing your modifications/validations and then returning `true`?

Comment: but then it not setting $('[id$=hiddentime]').val(myDate); inside that script since it submits the form without executing that script

Comment: Sorry guyz, my bad, I just checked with the "Submit" button again, it worked fine. Thanks to all of you.